# Insert <tr> to <tbody> in angular 5 dynamically

Tags: angular

following this https://blog.thecodecampus.de/angular-2-dynamically-render-components/#comment-789, I was able to create the child component dynamically on click of a link. Except my parent component is

parent.html

```
     <table>
     <thead>
         <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody #parent>
      </tbody>
      </table>
```

Child component.html:

```
        <tr><td>Blue</td><td>23</td></tr>
```

Child component.ts:

```
       selector:"app-tr-rows";
```

Now, when the tr is inserted in the tbody, firefox inspector gives:

```
     <app-tr-rows>
           <tr><td>Blue</td><td>23</td></tr>
     </app-tr-rows>
```

which causes all the child rows to appear on Name column only. What's the way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the child component selector to `tr[app-row]`.

This means that the selector for that component is any `tr` tag with the `app-row` attribute. When the component is initialised, it will no longer need to create the `app-tr-rows` tag. It will instead create a `tr` tag.

Then, change the parent template to use `ng-template`, like this:

```
<tbody>
  <ng-template #parent></ng-template>
</tbody>
```

This way the row component will be added as a child of the `tbody`, not as a sibling.

Finally, remove the `tr` tag from the child template, so it becomes:

```
<td>Blue</td><td>23</td>
```

**[Here is a StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zalqan?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)**

Comment: if could I could hug you a billion times. Thanks...worked like a charm! Is the main secret weapon the selector?

Comment: Glad to help. Yes, it is. It stops everything from being wrapped in `app-tr-rows`